# "bin/rails: No such file or directory" w/ Ruby 2 & Rails 4 on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0

While following the Rails 4 **Beta** version of Michael Hartl's *[Ruby on Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book?version=4.0#top)*, my app fails to start on Heroku, but runs fine locally with `bundle exec rails server`.  Checking `heroku logs -t` reveals the following error:

```
$ heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
$ heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server 
-p 33847 -e $RAILS_ENV`
$ app[web.1]: bash: bin/rails: No such file or directory
$ heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
$ heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
$ heroku[web.1]: Error R99 (Platform error) -> Failed to launch the 
dyno within 10 seconds
$ heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
```

If I `heroku run bash` and check the `bin` directory, I can see that there is **not** a `rails` executable:

```
~$ ls bin
erb  gem  irb  node rdoc  ri  ruby  testrb
```

What have I done wrong?  I followed the tutorial exactly.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

After struggling with this for a bit, I noticed that my Rails 4 project had a `/bin` directory, unlike some older Rails 3 projects I had cloned.  `/bin` contains 3 files, `bundle`, `rails`, and `rake`, but these weren't making it to Heroku because I had `bin` in my global `.gitignore` file.

This is a pretty common ignore rule if you work with Git and other languages (Java, etc.), so to fix this:

1. Remove `bin` from `~/.gitignore`
2. Run `bundle install`
3. Commit your
   changes with `git add .` and `git commit -m "Add bin back"`
4. Push your changes to Heroku with `git push heroku master`

Comment: There is a Heroku guide on running Rails4 applications on Heroku - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails4

Comment: Yep, it mentions not having bin in your .gitignore, but the tutorial doesn't.  Just thought I would create this in case someone else has a similar problem.

Comment: @justingarrick do you really need to run `bundle install`?  Seems like an extra step.

Comment: Make sure it's not in your global gitignore. That's what bit me.

Comment: I had the same problem for Dokku: 502 bad gateway. Thanks for the help.

Comment: although i removed /bin dir from .gitignore file, it doesn't get pushed to git repo, whats the issue.

Answer (score 105):

I had this problem also since I upgraded to rails 4.0.0

Run this command

```
rake rails:update:bin
```

You can go here for more info
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails4

Comment: Good info for those that are upgrading from Rails 3, etc., but the problem in the question occurred in a new application.  Also, this won't help you if you have those directories gitignored, because they still won't get git pushed to Heroku.

Comment: Moving to Rails 4.0.0, this was definitely the problem.

Comment: Issuing this command helped me getting my heroku app running again. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `rake app:update:bin` for Rails 6+ as of this writing

Answer (score 9):

**Steps** :

> 1. `bundle config --delete bin`         # Turn off Bundler's stub generator
> 2. `rake rails:update:bin`               # Use the new Rails 4 executables
> 3. `git add bin or git add bin -f`      # Add bin/ to source control
> 4. `git commit -a -m "you commit message"`
> 5. `git push heroku master`
> 6. `heroku open`

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue because the permissions on my `~/bin` directory were `644` instead of `755`.  Running `rake rails:update:bin` locally (on Mac/*nix) and then pushing the changes fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the very same problem that you did. The issue lied in the fact that the bin folder was never pushed to the heroku repository.

I looked, I looked, and then I looked again, there was no rule in the .gitignore file for the bin/ folder...

Then, after a lot of pain and anguish, I realized that a couple of months before I had created a global .gitignore that would ignore all bin folders of all my repositories (why lord, why??).

I deleted the global .gitignore, and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

We didn't have a myapp/bin directory in our rails 4 app, so we created one and then copied in the my app/script/rails file, plus the bundle and rake files from under rvm/ruby/bin and then added these to the repo for git and pushed it up to heroku and all was well.

Answer (score 0):

On rails 5.2.6, rake app:update:bin worked for me. Now deployment to heroku is working.

Answer (score -1):

I can confirm running `rake rails:update:bin` works, as said by @Ryan Taylor.

I think I had this problem because I originally created this Rails app on Windows. Running the command above on Linux solved for me.

Also, on changing from Windows to Linux for development, it is a good idea to delete `Gemfile.lock` file and run `bundle install` to generate it again without Windows specific gems listed there.