# Heroku App Crash H10 - bash: bin/rails: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am having an issue with my deployment. My test env locally works great with no errors. When I push to Heroku I get this:

```
2013-07-17T15:54:04.619297+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: bin/rails: No such file or directory
2013-07-17T15:54:07.240398+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-07-17T15:54:07.255379+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-07-17T15:54:13.467325+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R99 (Platform error) -> Failed to launch the dyno within 10 seconds
2013-07-17T15:54:13.467325+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2013-07-17T15:54:58.714647+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=radiant-thicket-1062.herokuapp.com fwd="174.4.33.188" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

I am unsure where anything is calling bin/rails or how to solve this. I can't find any information on this anywhere else with the H10. It's like I'm the only person to ever experience this (unlikely..)!

I'd appreciate any insight or help. Thank you!

Comment: Make sure you're on cedar stack. Need more information to give you anymore advice. Rails -v, rvm, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem - it's quite simple:

```
heroku config:set PATH=bin:vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

I found the solution here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions

Comment: Don't set or change your PATH value the buildpack will set it for you. Modifying PATH can actually cause this problem.

Answer (score 42):

You're missing the `bin` folder that was added in Rails 4. Run `rake rails:update:bin` to create it, then make a commit and push to Heroku.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the path won't necessarily help as it's looking for a 'bin' directory under your project directory, which is standard now under rails 4. Go see the answers under ["bin/rails: No such file or directory" w/ Ruby 2 & Rails 4 on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17583439/bin-rails-no-such-file-or-directory-w-ruby-2-rails-4-on-heroku) for more information.