# Heroku Application Error when opening Rails Tutorial Sample App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

The app works perfectly in development, but it won't open in Heroku.  I've executed heroku run rake db:migrate, and I have the pg gem in my Gemfile. I'm a newbie so any help interpreting the logs is greatly appreciated (see logs below Gemfile).

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2.0'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'
gem 'faker', '1.1.2'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.4'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.9'
gem 'execjs', '1.4.0'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.7'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
  # The following optional lines are part of the advanced setup.
  gem 'guard-rspec', '2.5.0'
  gem 'spork-rails', github: 'sporkrb/spork-rails'
  gem 'guard-spork', '1.5.0'
  gem 'childprocess', '0.3.6'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.0.0'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.2.0'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', '1.3.0', :require => false
  gem 'database_cleaner', github: 'bmabey/database_cleaner'

  # Uncomment this line on OS X.
  # gem 'growl', '1.0.3'

  # Uncomment these lines on Linux.
  # gem 'libnotify', '0.8.0'

  # Uncomment these lines on Windows.
  # gem 'rb-notifu', '0.0.4'
  # gem 'win32console', '1.3.2'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.2.1'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

Heroku Logs

```
2013-08-07T07:20:48.191527+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-08-07T07:20:55.721992+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2013-08-07T07:20:55.721707+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R99 (Platform error) -> Failed to launch the dyno within 10 seconds
2013-08-07T07:30:55.539343+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-08-07T07:30:59.366275+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 38150 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-08-07T07:31:00.198943+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: bin/rails: No such file or directory
2013-08-07T07:31:01.456201+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-08-07T07:31:01.468706+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-08-07T07:31:09.462367+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R99 (Platform error) -> Failed to launch the dyno within 10 seconds
2013-08-07T07:31:09.462587+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2013-08-07T07:41:32.224698+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-08-07T07:48:01.169884+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to down
2013-08-08T16:28:35+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2013-08-08T16:30:21.321235+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 584d5dd by lionelramos@hotmail.com
2013-08-08T16:30:21.361053+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v9 created by lionelramos@hotmail.com
2013-08-08T16:30:21.408802+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 584d5dd by lionelramos@hotmail.com
2013-08-08T16:30:21.776973+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2013-08-08T16:30:22+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2013-08-08T16:30:27.193957+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 54367 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-08-08T16:30:28.323977+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: bin/rails: No such file or directory
2013-08-08T16:30:29.641426+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-08-08T16:30:29.653233+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-08-08T16:30:29.654038+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-08-08T16:30:33.329442+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 46009 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-08-08T16:30:33.987177+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: bin/rails: No such file or directory
2013-08-08T16:30:35.114974+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-08-08T16:30:35.131772+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-08-08T16:30:39.524101+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=safe-everglades-1070.herokuapp.com fwd="67.190.24.163" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-08-08T16:30:39.758914+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=safe-everglades-1070.herokuapp.com fwd="67.190.24.163" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-08-08T16:30:43.397387+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2013-08-08T16:30:43.397150+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R99 (Platform error) -> Failed to launch the dyno within 10 seconds
2013-08-08T16:31:18.425700+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=safe-everglades-1070.herokuapp.com fwd="67.190.24.163" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-08-08T16:31:18.591149+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=safe-everglades-1070.herokuapp.com fwd="67.190.24.163" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-08-08T16:31:28.469629+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=safe-everglades-1070.herokuapp.com fwd="67.190.24.163" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-08-08T16:31:28.701988+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=safe-everglades-1070.herokuapp.com fwd="67.190.24.163" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-08-08T16:32:03.650372+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=safe-everglades-1070.herokuapp.com fwd="67.190.24.163" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-08-08T16:32:03.853597+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=safe-everglades-1070.herokuapp.com fwd="67.190.24.163" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-08-08T16:32:48.963826+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=safe-everglades-1070.herokuapp.com fwd="67.190.24.163" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-08-08T16:32:49.453647+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=safe-everglades-1070.herokuapp.com fwd="67.190.24.163" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-08-08T16:33:47.304289+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=safe-everglades-1070.herokuapp.com fwd="67.190.24.163" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-08-08T16:33:47.595892+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=safe-everglades-1070.herokuapp.com fwd="67.190.24.163" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-08-08T16:38:29.879368+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-08-08T16:38:33.796829+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 8363 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-08-08T16:38:34.801683+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: bin/rails: No such file or directory
2013-08-08T16:38:36.319899+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-08-08T16:38:36.336545+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-08-08T16:38:44.044665+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R99 (Platform error) -> Failed to launch the dyno within 10 seconds
2013-08-08T16:38:44.044934+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2013-08-08T16:39:12.507540+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by lionelramos@hotmail.com
2013-08-08T16:39:17.159747+00:00 heroku[run.7755]: Awaiting client
2013-08-08T16:39:17.205425+00:00 heroku[run.7755]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2013-08-08T16:39:18.501286+00:00 heroku[run.7755]: State changed from starting to up
2013-08-08T16:39:22.316247+00:00 heroku[run.7755]: State changed from up to complete
2013-08-08T16:39:22.300345+00:00 heroku[run.7755]: Process exit
ed with status 0
2013-08-08T16:39:40.520653+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-08-08T16:39:44.026519+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 16810 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-08-08T16:39:44.559308+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: bin/rails: No such file or directory
2013-08-08T16:39:45.606931+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-08-08T16:39:45.623487+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-08-08T16:39:48.820868+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=safe-everglades-1070.herokuapp.com fwd="67.190.24.163" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-08-08T16:39:49.063725+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=safe-everglades-1070.herokuapp.com fwd="67.190.24.163" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-08-08T16:39:54.502024+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2013-08-08T16:39:54.501841+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R99 (Platform error) -> Failed to launch the dyno within 10 seconds
2013-08-08T16:40:36.227715+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-08-08T16:40:40.500864+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 18671 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-08-08T16:40:41.165579+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: bin/rails: No such file or directory
2013-08-08T16:40:42.992519+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Proc
ess exited with status 127
2013-08-08T16:40:43.004269+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-08-08T16:49:52+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2013-08-08T16:50:16.937021+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 6d2b02d by lionelramos@hotmail.com
2013-08-08T16:50:16.974839+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v10 created by lionelramos@hotmail.com
2013-08-08T16:50:17.016095+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 6d2b02d by lionelramos@hotmail.com
2013-08-08T16:50:17.300414+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-08-08T16:50:17+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2013-08-08T16:50:33.077888+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by lionelramos@hotmail.com
2013-08-08T16:50:36.009069+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 53499 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-08-08T16:50:36.872168+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: bin/rails: No such file or directory
2013-08-08T16:50:38.282632+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-08-08T16:50:38.282632+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-08-08T16:50:38.374822+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-08-08T16:50:40.217842+00:00 heroku[run.9716]: Awaiting client
2013-08-08T16:50:40.270232+00:00 heroku[run.9716]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2013-08-08T16:50:41.485820+00:00 heroku[run.9716]: State changed from starting to up
2013-08-08T16:50:44.073086+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 4578 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-08-08T16:50:45.504279+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: bin/rails: No such file or directory
2013-08-08T16:50:46.122292+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R99 (Platform error) -> Failed to launch the dyno within 10 seconds
2013-08-08T16:50:46.122487+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2013-08-08T16:50:47.269304+00:00 heroku[run.9716]: State changed from up to complete
2013-08-08T16:50:47.331637+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-08-08T16:50:47.348525+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-08-08T16:50:47.251417+00:00 heroku[run.9716]: Process exited with status 0
2013-08-08T16:51:18.817119+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by lionelramos@hotmail.com
2013-08-08T16:51:25.576114+00:00 heroku[run.9125]: Awaiting client
2013-08-08T16:51:25.605481+00:00 heroku[run.9125]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2013-08-08T16:51:27.036113+00:00 heroku[run.9125]: State changed from starting to up
2013-08-08T16:51:30.821318+00:00 heroku[run.9125]: Process exited with status 0
2013-08-08T16:51:30.838410+00:00 heroku[run.9125]: State changed from up to complete
2013-08-08T16:52:05.045633+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=safe-everglades-1070.herokuapp.com fwd="67.190.24.163" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-08-08T16:52:05.283192+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=safe-everglades-1070.herokuapp.com fwd="67.190.24.163" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-08-08T16:52:29.661946+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=safe-everglades-1070.herokuapp.com fwd="67.190.24.163" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-08-08T16:52:29.904570+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=safe-everglades-1070.herokuapp.com fwd="67.190.24.163" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Comment: Have you tried the solution in this thread? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17704754/heroku-app-crash-h10-bash-bin-rails-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: @Dhaulagiri It didn't work, but it may have improved the situation.  I reran the logs, see the [gist](https://gist.github.com/ltrainpr/6187461).

Comment: Looks like you are getting the same error.  What is the output of heroku config -s | grep PATH and heroku run "ruby -v"?

Comment: @Dhaulagiri PATH=bin:vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin Running `ruby -v` attached to terminal... up, run.1725
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: Have you read this thread? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17583439/bin-rails-no-such-file-or-directory-w-ruby-2-rails-4-on-heroku

Comment: @Dhaulagiri rake rails:update:bin solved the problem. ~/.gitignore was fine (did not include bin).  Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing `rake db:create`.

Comment: Ran rake db:create and got this: db/development.sqlite3 already exists
db/test.sqlite3 already exists

Comment: Run it in heroku. Not your dev / test environment.