# Failed in deploying to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, terminal

When deploying my Ruby on Rails app to heroku, I get `an application error page`, [here](https://secret-fjord-97193.herokuapp.com)

When typing heroku logs in my terminal line, I get the following information which I do not know how to process? Can anyone tell me what I need to do to solve the issue?

```
2016-07-11T11:12:32.333185+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v2 created by nicholas.wenzel@internsgopro.com
2016-07-11T11:12:32.333065+00:00 heroku[api]: Enable Logplex by nicholas.wenzel@internsgopro.com
2016-07-11T11:13:09.721816+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Ruby app
2016-07-11T11:13:09.721807+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-07-11T11:17:24.819913+00:00 heroku[api]: Set LANG, RACK_ENV, RAILS_ENV, RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES, SECRET_KEY_BASE config vars by nicholas.wenzel@internsgopro.com
2016-07-11T11:17:24.820006+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v3 created by nicholas.wenzel@internsgopro.com
2016-07-11T11:17:25.503120+00:00 heroku[api]: Attach DATABASE (@ref:postgresql-rectangular-14432) by nicholas.wenzel@internsgopro.com
2016-07-11T11:17:25.503211+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v4 created by nicholas.wenzel@internsgopro.com
2016-07-11T11:17:25.942507+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by nicholas.wenzel@internsgopro.com
2016-07-11T11:17:25.943837+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v5 created by nicholas.wenzel@internsgopro.com
2016-07-11T11:17:25.943474+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy d12e1f4 by nicholas.wenzel@internsgopro.com
2016-07-11T11:17:26.383271+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-07-11T11:17:26.383275+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2016-07-11T11:17:28.217297+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 40742 -e production`
2016-07-11T11:17:29.955175+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: bin/rails: No such file or directory
2016-07-11T11:17:30.862720+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2016-07-11T11:17:30.877538+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-07-11T11:17:30.878343+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-07-11T11:17:33.707325+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 13244 -e production`
2016-07-11T11:17:35.968520+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: bin/rails: No such file or directory
2016-07-11T11:17:37.094194+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-07-11T11:17:37.083048+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2016-07-11T11:17:38.324735+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=secret-fjord-97193.herokuapp.com request_id=2fb7b183-2953-4290-a56e-cc4ab8000f5b fwd="31.179.119.186" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-07-11T11:17:39.262796+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=secret-fjord-97193.herokuapp.com request_id=7a1d15d7-9ce4-44b2-ab29-3853c0223b06 fwd="31.179.119.186" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-07-11T11:18:47.008968+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by nicholas.wenzel@internsgopro.com
2016-07-11T11:18:50.699273+00:00 heroku[run.8742]: Awaiting client
2016-07-11T11:18:50.745068+00:00 heroku[run.8742]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2016-07-11T11:18:50.800462+00:00 heroku[run.8742]: State changed from starting to up
2016-07-11T11:18:57.245641+00:00 heroku[run.8742]: Process exited with status 0
2016-07-11T11:18:57.263781+00:00 heroku[run.8742]: State changed from up to complete
2016-07-11T11:19:05.165252+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=secret-fjord-97193.herokuapp.com request_id=1847e12b-66b1-44a9-8f5a-b50505aeb464 fwd="31.179.119.186" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-07-11T11:19:41.487888+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=secret-fjord-97193.herokuapp.com request_id=631d71c7-d998-48d6-acd8-5ea507ba4554 fwd="31.179.119.186" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-07-11T11:20:03.603738+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=secret-fjord-97193.herokuapp.com request_id=ceef2839-b13b-4794-9e17-1a87b8b344f8 fwd="31.179.119.186" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Comment: you probably deleted `bin/rails`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17704754/heroku-app-crash-h10-bash-bin-rails-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: I checked. The bin/rails file is in the folder. I also did run the command rails:update:bin

Answer (score 1):

Run rake **rails:update:bin** to create a bin folder that was added in rails4, then make a commit and push to Heroku. Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried this. . When I do git status, there is nothing to commit. Although the terminal asks me to overwrite files.