# Vague error message from Heroku when pushing, logs unhelpful

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

So I'm using Rails 4.0 and Ruby 2.0.  My app works locally and I'm just trying to push it to Heroku.  When I push it, my terminal indicates that everything worked.  However, when I run "Heroku open", I get this error message:

"Application Error

An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.

If you are the application owner, check your logs for details."

So I check my Heroku logs and get this:

```
2013-10-09T18:11:04+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Ruby/Rails app
2013-10-09T18:44:51+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2013-10-09T18:52:38.087581+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2013-10-09T18:52:42.873303+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2013-10-09T18:52:44.057184+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:90:in `select'
2013-10-09T18:52:44.057184+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-10-09 18:52:44] ERROR SignalException: SIGTERM
2013-10-09T18:52:52.698902+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At least one process failed to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM
2013-10-09T18:52:52.699100+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping remaining processes with SIGKILL
2013-10-09T18:52:55.089017+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2013-10-09T18:52:55.117506+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2013-10-09T19:09:30+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2013-10-09T19:09:56+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Ruby/Rails app
2013-10-09T19:12:56+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2013-10-09T19:13:19+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Ruby/Rails app
2013-10-09T19:14:39+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2013-10-09T19:15:08+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Ruby/Rails app
2013-10-09T19:17:15+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2013-10-09T19:17:43+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Ruby/Rails app
2013-10-09T19:18:02+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2013-10-09T19:18:24+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Ruby/Rails app
2013-10-09T19:20:12+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2013-10-09T19:21:40.262707+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2013-10-09T19:21:40+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2013-10-09T19:21:45.164416+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 51664 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-10-09T19:21:45.824512+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: bin/rails: No such file or directory
2013-10-09T19:21:47.372719+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-10-09T19:21:47.374233+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-10-09T19:21:47.360556+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-10-09T19:21:52.782769+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 21782 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-10-09T19:21:53.632718+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: bin/rails: No such file or directory
2013-10-09T19:21:55.247743+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-10-09T19:21:55.260010+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-10-09T19:22:00.902528+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=rocky-brushlands-1229.herokuapp.com fwd="72.74.241.162" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-10-09T19:22:15.746476+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=rocky-brushlands-1229.herokuapp.com fwd="72.74.241.162" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-10-09T19:22:19.270286+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=rocky-brushlands-1229.herokuapp.com fwd="72.74.241.162" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-10-09T19:22:19.314670+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=rocky-brushlands-1229.herokuapp.com fwd="72.74.241.162" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-10-09T19:22:17.799045+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=rocky-brushlands-1229.herokuapp.com fwd="72.74.241.162" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-10-09T19:24:19.549828+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=rocky-brushlands-1229.herokuapp.com fwd="72.74.241.162" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-10-09T19:24:22.196517+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=rocky-brushlands-1229.herokuapp.com fwd="72.74.241.162" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-10-09T19:24:22.302682+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=rocky-brushlands-1229.herokuapp.com fwd="72.74.241.162" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-10-09T19:22:19.122401+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=rocky-brushlands-1229.herokuapp.com fwd="72.74.241.162" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-10-09T19:22:17.689844+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=rocky-brushlands-1229.herokuapp.com fwd="72.74.241.162" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-10-09T19:25:40.152185+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=rocky-brushlands-1229.herokuapp.com fwd="72.74.241.162" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-10-09T19:25:40.254083+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=rocky-brushlands-1229.herokuapp.com fwd="72.74.241.162" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-10-09T19:22:18.422342+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=rocky-brushlands-1229.herokuapp.com fwd="72.74.241.162" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-10-09T19:25:48.595371+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/simulation host=rocky-brushlands-1229.herokuapp.com fwd="72.74.241.162" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-10-09T19:25:48.706113+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=rocky-brushlands-1229.herokuapp.com fwd="72.74.241.162" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-10-09T19:24:19.441344+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=rocky-brushlands-1229.herokuapp.com fwd="72.74.241.162" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-10-09T19:29:30.447734+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-10-09T19:29:39.212672+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 8011 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-10-09T19:29:40.275800+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: bin/rails: No such file or directory
2013-10-09T19:29:41.536523+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-10-09T19:29:41.553119+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-10-09T19:29:43.142915+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=rocky-brushlands-1229.herokuapp.com fwd="72.74.241.162" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-10-09T19:29:49.393166+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R99 (Platform error) -> Failed to launch the dyno within 10 seconds
2013-10-09T19:29:49.393401+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2013-10-09T19:30:32.885333+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by benjamin_clayman@alumni.brown.edu
2013-10-09T19:30:40.320116+00:00 heroku[run.5508]: Awaiting client
2013-10-09T19:30:40.377694+00:00 heroku[run.5508]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2013-10-09T19:30:41.612272+00:00 heroku[run.5508]: State changed from starting to up
2013-10-09T19:30:51.132253+00:00 heroku[run.5508]: Process exited with status 0
2013-10-09T19:30:51.164260+00:00 heroku[run.5508]: State changed from up to complete
2013-10-09T19:31:07.432378+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:seed` by benjamin_clayman@alumni.brown.edu
2013-10-09T19:31:14.013906+00:00 heroku[run.1827]: Awaiting client
2013-10-09T19:31:14.080713+00:00 heroku[run.1827]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:seed`
2013-10-09T19:31:15.414436+00:00 heroku[run.1827]: State changed from starting to up
2013-10-09T19:31:19.041011+00:00 heroku[run.1827]: Process exited with status 1
2013-10-09T19:31:19.056727+00:00 heroku[run.1827]: State changed from up to complete
2013-10-09T19:32:08.619874+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-10-09T19:32:11.337276+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:seed` by benjamin_clayman@alumni.brown.edu
2013-10-09T19:32:14.419913+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 10397 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-10-09T19:32:15.072660+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: bin/rails: No such file or directory
2013-10-09T19:32:16.194007+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-10-09T19:32:16.208094+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-10-09T19:32:21.776095+00:00 heroku[run.5181]: Awaiting client
2013-10-09T19:32:21.872776+00:00 heroku[run.5181]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:seed`
2013-10-09T19:32:22.981513+00:00 heroku[run.5181]: State changed from starting to up
2013-10-09T19:32:27.556289+00:00 heroku[run.5181]: Client connection closed. Sending SIGHUP to all processes
2013-10-09T19:32:29.032961+00:00 heroku[run.5181]: Process exited with status 1
2013-10-09T19:32:29.087562+00:00 heroku[run.5181]: State changed from up to complete
2013-10-09T19:42:43.713377+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-10-09T19:42:48.645184+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 4793 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-10-09T19:42:49.240477+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: bin/rails: No such file or directory
2013-10-09T19:42:50.587908+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-10-09T19:42:50.602229+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-10-09T19:42:46+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2013-10-09T19:43:18.483470+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 22ad50c by benjamin_clayman@alumni.brown.edu
2013-10-09T19:43:18.496059+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v19 created by benjamin_clayman@alumni.brown.edu
2013-10-09T19:43:18.648420+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-10-09T19:43:18+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2013-10-09T19:43:24.039482+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 37273 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-10-09T19:43:24.917501+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: bin/rails: No such file or directory
2013-10-09T19:43:26.321155+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-10-09T19:43:26.339466+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-10-09T19:43:34.291081+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R99 (Platform error) -> Failed to launch the dyno within 10 seconds
2013-10-09T19:43:34.291514+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2013-10-09T19:43:54.377170+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=rocky-brushlands-1229.herokuapp.com fwd="72.74.241.162" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-10-09T19:43:57.816484+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=rocky-brushlands-1229.herokuapp.com fwd="72.74.241.162" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-10-09T19:43:58.025631+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=rocky-brushlands-1229.herokuapp.com fwd="72.74.241.162" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-10-09T19:43:59.803749+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=rocky-brushlands-1229.herokuapp.com fwd="72.74.241.162" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-10-09T19:43:59.891121+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=rocky-brushlands-1229.herokuapp.com fwd="72.74.241.162" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

It looks like the app is crashing (error code of H10) but I have no idea why.

Any help would be greatly appreciated; have been trying to get this app online for way too long!

Thanks,
Mariogs

So these are the logs when I  try to load the "/ladder" page:

```
2013-10-10T20:14:00.495559+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/ladder" for 75.69.143.242 at 2013-10-10 20:14:00 +0000
2013-10-10T20:14:00.508841+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PagesController#ladder as HTML
2013-10-10T20:14:00.508841+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PagesController#ladder as HTML
2013-10-10T20:14:00.495559+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/ladder" for 75.69.143.242 at 2013-10-10 20:14:00 +0000
2013-10-10T20:14:00.529363+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pages/ladder.html.haml within layouts/application (0.4ms)
2013-10-10T20:14:00.529363+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pages/ladder.html.haml within layouts/application (0.4ms)
2013-10-10T20:14:00.555095+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_nav.html.erb (0.5ms)
2013-10-10T20:14:00.562435+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.1ms)
2013-10-10T20:14:00.562435+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.1ms)
2013-10-10T20:14:00.555095+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_nav.html.erb (0.5ms)
2013-10-10T20:14:00.565824+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 57ms (Views: 37.3ms | ActiveRecord: 12.4ms)
2013-10-10T20:14:00.565824+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 57ms (Views: 37.3ms | ActiveRecord: 12.4ms)
2013-10-10T20:14:00.576713+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ladder host=rocky-brushlands-1229.herokuapp.com fwd="75.69.143.242" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=94ms status=304 bytes=0
2013-10-10T20:14:01.000519+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/knitting250px.png host=rocky-brushlands-1229.herokuapp.com fwd="75.69.143.242" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=9ms status=404 bytes=728
2013-10-10T20:14:00.999368+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-10-10T20:14:00.998228+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/assets/knitting250px.png" for 75.69.143.242 at 2013-10-10 20:14:00 +0000
2013-10-10T20:14:00.999368+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/knitting250px.png"):
2013-10-10T20:14:00.999368+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
2013-10-10T20:14:00.999368+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2013-10-10T20:14:00.999368+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
2013-10-10T20:14:00.999368+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2013-10-10T20:14:00.999368+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
2013-10-10T20:14:00.999368+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
2013-10-10T20:14:00.999590+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2013-10-10T20:14:00.999590+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2013-10-10T20:14:00.999590+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
2013-10-10T20:14:00.999590+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
2013-10-10T20:14:00.999590+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
2013-10-10T20:14:00.999590+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
2013-10-10T20:14:00.999590+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2013-10-10T20:14:00.999590+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
2013-10-10T20:14:00.999730+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2013-10-10T20:14:00.999730+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2013-10-10T20:14:00.999368+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
2013-10-10T20:14:00.999368+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
2013-10-10T20:14:00.996893+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/assets/knitting250px.png" for 75.69.143.242 at 2013-10-10 20:14:00 +0000
2013-10-10T20:14:00.999590+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2013-10-10T20:14:00.999730+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-10-10T20:14:00.999730+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-10-10T20:14:00.999730+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/knitting250px.png"):
2013-10-10T20:14:00.999730+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2013-10-10T20:14:00.999590+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2013-10-10T20:14:00.999730+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-10-10T20:14:00.999730+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2013-10-10T20:14:00.999730+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2013-10-10T20:14:01.000144+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
2013-10-10T20:14:01.000144+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
2013-10-10T20:14:01.000144+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
2013-10-10T20:14:01.000144+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2013-10-10T20:14:01.000144+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2013-10-10T20:14:01.000144+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
2013-10-10T20:14:01.000144+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
2013-10-10T20:14:01.000144+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
2013-10-10T20:14:00.999730+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
2013-10-10T20:14:01.000286+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
2013-10-10T20:14:01.000286+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2013-10-10T20:14:01.000144+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2013-10-10T20:14:01.000286+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
2013-10-10T20:14:01.000286+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2013-10-10T20:14:01.000286+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2013-10-10T20:14:01.000144+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
2013-10-10T20:14:01.000286+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2013-10-10T20:14:01.000286+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-10-10T20:14:01.000286+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-10-10T20:14:01.074531+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=rocky-brushlands-1229.herokuapp.com fwd="75.69.143.242" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=7ms status=304 bytes=0
2013-10-10T20:14:01.000286+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2013-10-10T20:14:01.000286+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
2013-10-10T20:14:00.647780+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/application-a792af9cec9481fd62c86dd7b997071b.css host=rocky-brushlands-1229.herokuapp.com fwd="75.69.143.242" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=17ms status=304 bytes=0
```

I have no idea why the @ladder instance variable seems to be empty...

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17583439/bin-rails-no-such-file-or-directory-w-ruby-2-rails-4-on-heroku

Comment: So great news: /simulation now works after i ran "heroku pg:reset <name of my db>.  So the only thing left to fix is the /ladder page.  It works locally and I don't get any errors that I notice in the logs.  Basically I'm just storing an array of player names in an array, passing the instance variable holding that array to /ladder and looping through it to create an ordered list.  No idea why Heroku doesn't like it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error is clear:

```
bash: bin/rails: No such file or directory
```

Rails 4 requires a bin directory
It even provides a handy rake task for you

```
 rake rails:update:bin
```

In future consult the Heroku documentation

[Rails 4 on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails4)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @TheIrishGuy.  So we're definitely getting somewhere.  I did what you said and now my app is (sort of) on Heroku.  However, the two main pages (/simulation and /ladder) don't work.  /simulation gives me "We're sorry but something went wrong" while /ladder displays nothing.  I've passed an instance variable to the view for /ladder and looped through it to display an ordered list.  Happy to post Heroku logs (tho unsure where to do this)...

Comment: Update: have added Heroku logs for when I try to access /ladder and /simulation.  See original question for them.  Thanks again for the help, guys.

Comment: Ok next, is you need to run the migrations, "ranking" does not exist in your heroku pg database. If you're using asset pipeline try heroku restart at your CL for the missing asset issue.

Comment: Gotcha, so I just did that and my logs show that everything worked but, when I run Heroku open, I have the same issue on /ladder and /simulation.  Do you mind looking at the logs above?

Comment: can you run your app locally in production mode? rails s -e production and get no errors?

After all this, its probably going to be a config issue as you have two different things "ranking" does not exist in your db so its either an error in your code or your db. And than you have the missing asset issue (all this is in the logs)

Comment: Interesting, OK so I just tried to run it in production mode locally and got the same error.  It says: "PG::ConnectionBad (FATAL:  database "SquashSimulator_production" does not exist
):" so I think when I was running my app locally before, it was using development, not production.  Potentially silly q: but how do I change this?  Have just googled around but don't want to mess with this given how close I think I am...

Comment: Updated logs above for "/ladder".  Page is totally blank, making me think the instance variable is empty when it gets passed to the view...no idea why that'd be the case tho

Comment: I no longer will help you out here, as you keep adding new problems and the original question has been answered. Open a new question on SO for more help.