# Heroku "h10" deployment error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

The client wants me to deploy to Heroku but I'm getting this arbitrary error that I've never seen before, it's the code=H10 I've looked it up can't find a solution.

What can I do to get this working?

```
[2013-11-30T20:19:44.316670+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 8943 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-11-30T20:19:45.271874+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: bin/rails: No such file or directory
2013-11-30T20:19:46.879243+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-11-30T20:19:46.866340+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-11-30T20:19:48.903992+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=mysterious-garden-5203.herokuapp.com fwd="188.237.135.33" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-11-30T20:19:48.938580+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=mysterious-garden-5203.herokuapp.com fwd="99.232.165.130" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-11-30T20:19:49.425344+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=mysterious-garden-5203.herokuapp.com fwd="99.232.165.130" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-11-30T20:19:52.208619+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=mysterious-garden-5203.herokuapp.com fwd="99.232.165.130" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-11-30T20:19:48.395497+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=mysterious-garden-5203.herokuapp.com fwd="188.237.135.33" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-11-30T20:19:53.810740+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=mysterious-garden-5203.herokuapp.com fwd="188.237.135.33" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-11-30T20:21:04.266971+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by anthony.panepinto101@gmail.com
2013-11-30T20:21:10.605103+00:00 heroku[run.6221]: Awaiting client
2013-11-30T20:21:10.639194+00:00 heroku[run.6221]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2013-11-30T20:21:10.757138+00:00 heroku[run.6221]: State changed from starting to up
2013-11-30T20:21:15.822068+00:00 heroku[run.6221]: Process exited with status 0
2013-11-30T20:21:15.824453+00:00 heroku[run.6221]: State changed from up to complete
2013-11-30T20:21:18.662286+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=mysterious-garden-5203.herokuapp.com fwd="99.232.165.130" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-11-30T20:21:21.883130+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=mysterious-garden-5203.herokuapp.com fwd="99.232.165.130" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-11-30T20:21:24.361857+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=mysterious-garden-5203.herokuapp.com fwd="99.232.165.130" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-11-30T20:21:36.326843+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=mysterious-garden-5203.herokuapp.com fwd="99.232.165.130" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-11-30T20:21:38.021198+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=mysterious-garden-5203.herokuapp.com fwd="99.232.165.130" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-11-30T20:19:49.277678+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=mysterious-garden-5203.herokuapp.com fwd="99.232.165.130" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-11-30T20:21:20.811719+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=mysterious-garden-5203.herokuapp.com fwd="99.232.165.130" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-11-30T20:21:59.426721+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=mysterious-garden-5203.herokuapp.com fwd="99.232.165.130" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-11-30T20:22:34.460939+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=mysterious-garden-5203.herokuapp.com fwd="188.237.135.33" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-11-30T20:22:34.698960+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=mysterious-garden-5203.herokuapp.com fwd="188.237.135.33" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-11-30T20:27:16+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2013-11-30T20:27:31+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Ruby app
2013-11-30T20:29:01+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2013-11-30T20:29:41.655655+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy de210d0 by anthony.panepinto101@gmail.com
2013-11-30T20:29:41.667691+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v6 created by anthony.panepinto101@gmail.com
2013-11-30T20:29:41+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2013-11-30T20:29:42.012784+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-11-30T20:29:47.742751+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 52743 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-11-30T20:29:48.718704+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: bin/rails: No such file or directory
2013-11-30T20:29:50.279616+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-11-30T20:29:50.265437+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-11-30T20:30:10.588040+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by anthony.panepinto101@gmail.com
2013-11-30T20:30:17.782910+00:00 heroku[run.6265]: State changed from starting to up
2013-11-30T20:30:17.870464+00:00 heroku[run.6265]: Awaiting client
2013-11-30T20:30:17.941360+00:00 heroku[run.6265]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2013-11-30T20:30:22.870197+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=mysterious-garden-5203.herokuapp.com fwd="99.232.165.130" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-11-30T20:30:25.862874+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-11-30T20:30:28.255953+00:00 heroku[run.6265]: State changed from up to complete
2013-11-30T20:30:28.249730+00:00 heroku[run.6265]: Process exited with status 0
2013-11-30T20:30:18.056417+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=mysterious-garden-5203.herokuapp.com fwd="99.232.165.130" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-11-30T20:30:34.018317+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 59707 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-11-30T20:30:35.033865+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: bin/rails: No such file or directory
2013-11-30T20:30:36.569901+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-11-30T20:30:36.553317+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-11-30T20:30:38.508150+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=mysterious-garden-5203.herokuapp.com fwd="99.232.165.130" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-11-30T20:30:51.113381+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle install` by anthony.panepinto101@gmail.com
2013-11-30T20:31:14.573048+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=mysterious-garden-5203.herokuapp.com fwd="99.232.165.130" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-11-30T20:31:26.256086+00:00 heroku[run.8925]: Awaiting client
2013-11-30T20:31:26.299875+00:00 heroku[run.8925]: Starting process with command `bundle install`
2013-11-30T20:31:26.976344+00:00 heroku[run.8925]: State changed from starting to up
2013-11-30T20:31:29.966901+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-11-30T20:31:31.689641+00:00 heroku[run.8925]: Process exited with status 0
2013-11-30T20:31:31.705410+00:00 heroku[run.8925]: State changed from up to complete
2013-11-30T20:31:35.164520+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 12407 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-11-30T20:31:37.267281+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-11-30T20:31:35.910209+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: bin/rails: No such file or directory
2013-11-30T20:31:37.258000+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-11-30T20:31:38.807957+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=mysterious-garden-5203.herokuapp.com fwd="99.232.165.130" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-11-30T20:31:43.545539+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=mysterious-garden-5203.herokuapp.com fwd="99.232.165.130" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-11-30T20:31:45.140204+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=mysterious-garden-5203.herokuapp.com fwd="99.232.165.130" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-11-30T20:30:40.008373+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=mysterious-garden-5203.herokuapp.com fwd="99.232.165.130" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-11-30T20:32:34.146621+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=mysterious-garden-5203.herokuapp.com fwd="99.232.165.130" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-11-30T20:45:00.433112+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=mysterious-garden-5203.herokuapp.com fwd="99.232.165.130" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-11-30T20:45:01.722773+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=mysterious-garden-5203.herokuapp.com fwd="99.232.165.130" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-11-30T20:47:05.943063+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-11-30T20:47:11.454202+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 47927 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-11-30T20:47:12.274441+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: bin/rails: No such file or directory
2013-11-30T20:47:13.512903+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-11-30T20:47:13.533141+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-11-30T21:03:34.571357+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=mysterious-garden-5203.herokuapp.com fwd="99.232.165.130" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-11-30T21:12:53.420511+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-11-30T21:12:58.650441+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 21179 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-11-30T21:12:59.519318+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: bin/rails: No such file or directory
2013-11-30T21:13:00.637356+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-11-30T21:13:00.637322+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-11-30T21:18:14+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2013-11-30T21:19:12.708550+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 22b636c by anthony.panepinto101@gmail.com
2013-11-30T21:19:12.724396+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v7 created by anthony.panepinto101@gmail.com
2013-11-30T21:19:12+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2013-11-30T21:19:13.408065+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-11-30T21:19:17.966201+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 50702 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-11-30T21:19:18.779748+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: bin/rails: No such file or directory
2013-11-30T21:19:19.915447+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-11-30T21:19:19.938463+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-11-30T21:19:27.007657+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=mysterious-garden-5203.herokuapp.com fwd="99.232.165.130" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-11-30T21:19:28.515986+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by anthony.panepinto101@gmail.com
2013-11-30T21:19:34.126476+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=mysterious-garden-5203.herokuapp.com fwd="99.232.165.130" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-11-30T21:19:35.179409+00:00 heroku[run.1468]: Awaiting client
2013-11-30T21:19:35.220245+00:00 heroku[run.1468]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2013-11-30T21:19:35.270945+00:00 heroku[run.1468]: State changed from starting to up
2013-11-30T21:19:41.854104+00:00 heroku[run.1468]: Process exited with status 0
2013-11-30T21:19:41.877101+00:00 heroku[run.1468]: State changed from up to complete
2013-11-30T21:19:43.695694+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=mysterious-garden-5203.herokuapp.com fwd="99.232.165.130" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-11-30T21:19:25.595178+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=mysterious-garden-5203.herokuapp.com fwd="99.232.165.130" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-11-30T21:19:42.541309+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=mysterious-garden-5203.herokuapp.com fwd="99.232.165.130" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
[new_work]$heroku restart
Restarting dynos... done
```

Comment: H10 means your app crashed - without access to the codebase, it's basically impossible to know why it crashed...  Feel free to catch me on #heroku or at jacobwgillespie@gmail.com.

Comment: Duplicate of [“bin/rails: No such file or directory” w/ Ruby 2 & Rails 4 on Heroku][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17583439/bin-rails-no-such-file-or-directory-w-ruby-2-rails-4-on-heroku