# No such file or directory when making system calls in Rails production env

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting some annoying errors when trying to make system calls in the rails console in a production environment.

```
Loading production environment (Rails 4.0.2)
2.0.0 :001 > `hostname`
bin/rails: No such file or directory - hostname
 => nil
```

It works fine in `irb`.

```
$ irb
2.0.0-p353 :001 > `hostname`
=> "app-1\n"
```

Same thing happens on my local machine. `rails c` is fine but `rails c production` gives the error above.

`ruby -v` outputs `ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [x86_64-linux]`

`rails --version` outputs `Rails 4.0.2`

I'm not really sure where to start debugging this so any advice is welcome! I have tried running `rake rails:update:bin`, based on ["bin/rails: No such file or directory" w/ Ruby 2 & Rails 4 on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17583439/bin-rails-no-such-file-or-directory-w-ruby-2-rails-4-on-heroku), but it didn't seem to make a difference. Any ideas?

Comment: I suspect the rails environment is doing something to your path.  What's the output of ENV['PATH'] in both?

Comment: They're very different! See http://pastebin.com/m6A22kcY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference in the PATH is the problem.  You'll need to look into your code or hosting environment to find out how the PATH is being set in the rails app.  It could be in the app itself, or whatever app server is launching the app - details can vary wildly.

Your rails console output:

```
"$HOME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin:$HOME/.rvm/bin:$PATH"
```

indicates that something is trying to add to the path, but it is inserting literal dollar signs instead of expanding the existing environment variable.  For example in a shell script setting a path, if you used the wrong quote symbols you'd see something like what you've got.

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin:$HOME/.rvm/bin:$PATH"   # right
export PATH='$HOME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin:$HOME/.rvm/bin:$PATH'   # wrong
```

I hope this points you in the right direction :)

Comment: Yep, that helps! I found that env variable being set somewhere in the codebase, no idea why especially as we're not on Ruby 1.9 anymore. Thanks for your help :)