# Heroku says Application Error and in the logs it say code=H10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I just pushed my rails app to heroku and and it gives me an error about the `favicon.ico`. The whole app crash and I can't understand the log error! Here's the heroku log :

```
    2014-06-28T11:52:22.913892+00:00 heroku[api]: Enable Logplex by pubudu.th@gmail.com
    2014-06-28T11:52:22.913963+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v2 created by pubudu.th@gmail.com
    2014-06-28T11:53:05+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
    2014-06-28T12:02:19.238438+00:00 heroku[api]: Set DATABASE_URL config vars by pubudu.th@gmail.com
    2014-06-28T12:02:19.238525+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v3 created by pubudu.th@gmail.com
    2014-06-28T12:02:19.335720+00:00 heroku[api]: Attach HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_ROSE resource by pubudu.th@gmail.com
    2014-06-28T12:02:18.853978+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by pubudu.th@gmail.com
    2014-06-28T12:02:19.335807+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v4 created by pubudu.th@gmail.com
    2014-06-28T12:02:19.482165+00:00 heroku[api]: Set LANG, RAILS_ENV, RACK_ENV, SECRET_KEY_BASE config vars by pubudu.th@gmail.com
    2014-06-28T12:02:19.482254+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v5 created by pubudu.th@gmail.com
    2014-06-28T12:02:19.571248+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy c8ef4fa by pubudu.th@gmail.com
    2014-06-28T12:02:19+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
    2014-06-28T12:02:19.571429+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v6 created by pubudu.th@gmail.com
    2014-06-28T12:02:24.420332+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: bin/rails: No such file or directory
    2014-06-28T12:02:25.645244+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
    2014-06-28T12:02:25.644545+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2014-06-28T12:02:23.681960+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 33163 -e production`
    2014-06-28T12:02:25.635263+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
    2014-06-28T12:02:32.049142+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: bin/rails: No such file or directory
    2014-06-28T12:02:30.951413+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 50449 -e production`
    2014-06-28T12:02:33.667800+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
    2014-06-28T12:02:33.684915+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2014-06-28T12:04:18.506293+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=enigmatic-spire-3449.herokuapp.com request_id=85c9ba66-ef48-40c0-8b6c-f8099c1a8f3d fwd="112.135.155.120" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
    2014-06-28T12:04:19.579248+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=enigmatic-spire-3449.herokuapp.com request_id=11e00d00-9a5b-49e8-85b4-5c2ba405a1d9 fwd="112.135.155.120" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
    2014-06-28T12:08:02+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
    2014-06-28T12:08:25.001553+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy a056fe1 by pubudu.th@gmail.com
    2014-06-28T12:08:25.001641+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v7 created by pubudu.th@gmail.com
    2014-06-28T12:08:25+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
    2014-06-28T12:08:25.138090+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
    2014-06-28T12:08:32.070448+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: bin/rails: No such file or directory
    2014-06-28T12:08:33.690681+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2014-06-28T12:08:31.118712+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 40290 -e production`
    2014-06-28T12:08:33.679032+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
    2014-06-28T12:10:38.288315+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=enigmatic-spire-3449.herokuapp.com request_id=3b6d2e26-6a16-4756-99a8-0a83815cdd9d fwd="112.135.155.120" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
    2014-06-28T12:10:39.340855+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=enigmatic-spire-3449.herokuapp.com request_id=5ca4e9c0-1924-4c15-b625-5374b0be2305 fwd="112.135.155.120" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the log **clearly** says, the error is,

```
bash: bin/rails: No such file or directory
```

Looking at other [StackOverflow answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17757488/184184), you might need to do,

```
rake rails:update:bin
```

Comment: I did that and now its showing this error `at=info method=GET path="/" host=enigmatic-spire-3449.herokuapp.com request_id=7c04a92e-bb5c-4615-9c83-0658a3a32ad8 fwd="112.135.155.120" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=21ms status=500 bytes=919`

Comment: Sorry... but im getting a new erro in the browser saying `We're sorry, but something went wrong.` in the logs the previous error is gone