# Cant push bin directory to github

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment, bin

I've made an app that works fine on localhost and I was making commits to github, having the repository there. Since I didn't started to make deploy on heroku I didn't noticed that the bin directory from the app folder wasn't pushing to github?? Ive tried everything, deleting the cache, the remote repository, but nothing... Why I cant push the bin directory to github?? Without the bin directory I can't deploy on heroku. Trows me the error: bin/rails directory not found.
I'm a bit confusing and tired of trying to push it to github.
Any suggestions/solutions would be very welcomed.

Comment: Check the .gitignore file to see if bin is ignored.

Comment: Checked it but nothing. Here are my .gitignore file contents:
`# Ignore the default SQLite database.
/db/*.sqlite3
/db/*.sqlite3-journal

# Ignore all logfiles and tempfiles.
/log/*.log
/tmp/**/*
/tmp/*
doc/api
doc/app
.c9
*.swp
.DS_Store
# /config/database.yml
# Ignore Spring files.
/spring/*.pid`

Comment: I am not a rails developer so can't help too much. I did find this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17583439/bin-rails-no-such-file-or-directory-w-ruby-2-rails-4-on-heroku

Comment: Thanks. Allready saw that post. The problem is that the folder bin is beeing created and updated on my localhost, inside my app folder, but when I try to push the changes to github, seems that the folder isnt tracked or soemthing (allready up to date). I have deleted the folder and run `rails:update:bin` again, and no luck... dont know what more to do. The problem here is I cant push the folder to github...

Comment: Add a new file to the bin directory and run a git status command from the top level directory. Does anything show?

Comment: Nop...its like having a phantom directory hehe. I'm trying to switch to bitbucket to see if problem persists. Its weird... on localhost:3000 its working perfectly!

Comment: It sounds like a problem with your git client so changing to bitbucket won't work. Try `git add --verbose` from your project directory but I don't think it will give you anything. Make sure you are at the top-level of the directory tree e.g above the bin folder. Try adding bin to your .gitignore and then removing it again. Restart your git client as well.

Comment: Hey, I've been able to add the bin folder using the cloud9 service. Seems that there is a problem with my git client as you said. I would have a look around after finishing deploy on heroku.