# Rails + Heroku: Application Error but logs look ok?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I've spent the last two hours trying to get my application up at https://young-refuge-9638.herokuapp.com/.

I've restarted my app, I've dropped the DB and then tried re-running the migrations again without any luck.

I'm compiling assets locally before pushing to heroku, committing the assets to Github and then trying to deploy to heroku.

After running `heroku logs` I can't see anything below that immediately stands out as the cause of the issue:

```
2015-05-31T15:09:05.366246+00:00 app[web.1]: Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
2015-05-31T15:09:06.072106+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2015-05-31T15:09:06.081798+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-05-31T17:18:41.922457+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-05-31T17:18:45.928761+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec thin start -R config.ru -e production -p 51004`
2015-05-31T17:18:48.558772+00:00 app[web.1]: Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
2015-05-31T17:18:48.439610+00:00 app[web.1]: Your Gemfile lists the gem pg (>= 0) more than once.
2015-05-31T17:18:48.439626+00:00 app[web.1]: You should probably keep only one of them.
2015-05-31T17:18:48.439629+00:00 app[web.1]: While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of just one of them later.
2015-05-31T17:18:48.558448+00:00 app[web.1]: bundler: command not found: thin
2015-05-31T17:18:49.636120+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-05-31T17:18:49.614625+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2015-05-31T20:21:07.607102+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-05-31T20:21:11.450300+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec thin start -R config.ru -e production -p 21662`
2015-05-31T20:21:13.501791+00:00 app[web.1]: Your Gemfile lists the gem pg (>= 0) more than once.
2015-05-31T20:21:13.501814+00:00 app[web.1]: You should probably keep only one of them.
2015-05-31T20:21:13.501817+00:00 app[web.1]: While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of just one of them later.
2015-05-31T20:21:13.576643+00:00 app[web.1]: bundler: command not found: thin
2015-05-31T20:21:13.576656+00:00 app[web.1]: Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
2015-05-31T20:21:14.423208+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-05-31T20:21:14.412694+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2015-06-01T09:07:40.300869+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 6d4aa09 by ryan@ryandrake.com
2015-06-01T09:07:40.300869+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v6 created by ryan@ryandrake.com
2015-06-01T09:07:40.445691+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-06-01T09:07:44.380708+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 47302 -e production`
2015-06-01T09:07:46.078253+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: bin/rails: No such file or directory
2015-06-01T09:07:46.848143+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2015-06-01T09:07:46.858373+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-06-01T09:07:46.859120+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-06-01T09:07:50.216433+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 39773 -e production`
2015-06-01T09:07:52.150455+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: bin/rails: No such file or directory
2015-06-01T09:07:52.993821+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-06-01T09:07:52.982708+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2015-06-01T09:09:23.659136+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=young-refuge-9638.herokuapp.com request_id=00895218-a778-4ab9-9eeb-7555ed3d9a24 fwd="49.197.32.79" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-06-01T09:09:25.416523+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=young-refuge-9638.herokuapp.com request_id=01462660-0690-42f4-8452-32b1ef71603f fwd="49.197.32.79" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-06-01T09:10:44.356406+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=young-refuge-9638.herokuapp.com request_id=e9c0966f-6526-4135-b32e-8df0890b5ba7 fwd="49.197.32.79" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-06-01T09:10:45.612458+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=young-refuge-9638.herokuapp.com request_id=041e9c0a-69da-4a40-a7d0-fa13248cf993 fwd="49.197.32.79" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-06-01T09:19:32.112120+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:setup` by ryan@ryandrake.com
2015-06-01T09:19:36.087374+00:00 heroku[run.4607]: Awaiting client
2015-06-01T09:19:36.157675+00:00 heroku[run.4607]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:setup`
2015-06-01T09:19:36.354911+00:00 heroku[run.4607]: State changed from starting to up
2015-06-01T09:19:46.418017+00:00 heroku[run.4607]: State changed from up to complete
2015-06-01T09:19:46.406724+00:00 heroku[run.4607]: Process exited with status 1
2015-06-01T09:43:11.062307+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-06-01T09:43:14.974528+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 20520 -e production`
2015-06-01T09:43:16.417276+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: bin/rails: No such file or directory
2015-06-01T09:43:17.172652+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-06-01T09:43:17.157636+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2015-06-01T09:59:57.447505+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 0836366 by ryan@ryandrake.com
2015-06-01T09:59:57.447505+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v7 created by ryan@ryandrake.com
2015-06-01T09:59:57.933412+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-06-01T10:00:01.379397+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 45758 -e production`
2015-06-01T10:00:03.274075+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: bin/rails: No such file or directory
2015-06-01T10:00:03.999342+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-06-01T10:00:04.000373+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-06-01T10:00:03.991012+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2015-06-01T10:00:10.896231+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 21218 -e production`
2015-06-01T10:00:12.780703+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: bin/rails: No such file or directory
2015-06-01T10:00:13.734295+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2015-06-01T10:00:13.747371+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-06-01T10:01:27.909816+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=young-refuge-9638.herokuapp.com request_id=fd154914-5054-42b4-859f-3fcf0dfd77b3 fwd="49.197.32.79" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-06-01T10:01:28.832902+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=young-refuge-9638.herokuapp.com request_id=fa37e8a9-b588-48cb-b4e7-25938d1162ec fwd="49.197.32.79" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-06-01T10:01:29.592927+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=young-refuge-9638.herokuapp.com request_id=4bbeb134-73de-4943-9fa1-f554cc5969fe fwd="49.197.32.79" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-06-01T10:01:34.348707+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=young-refuge-9638.herokuapp.com request_id=184c42cd-389c-4a3d-9760-6b174c5023cd fwd="49.197.32.79" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-06-01T10:01:35.617652+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=young-refuge-9638.herokuapp.com request_id=e28e16f5-a423-4b7c-ad02-6907c91784a5 fwd="49.197.32.79" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-06-01T10:01:52.893267+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:setup` by ryan@ryandrake.com
2015-06-01T10:01:58.401168+00:00 heroku[run.9758]: Awaiting client
2015-06-01T10:01:58.461834+00:00 heroku[run.9758]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:setup`
2015-06-01T10:01:58.665847+00:00 heroku[run.9758]: State changed from starting to up
2015-06-01T10:02:31.561059+00:00 heroku[run.9758]: State changed from up to complete
2015-06-01T10:02:31.550874+00:00 heroku[run.9758]: Process exited with status 0
2015-06-01T10:03:18.803810+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=young-refuge-9638.herokuapp.com request_id=09832d29-73e4-46db-80a1-a6bc7d3c7d3f fwd="49.197.32.79" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-06-01T10:03:19.665696+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=young-refuge-9638.herokuapp.com request_id=80cf06fe-69b9-4744-997b-fd7d493d666e fwd="49.197.32.79" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-06-01T10:03:28.157702+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by ryan@ryandrake.com
2015-06-01T10:03:32.559559+00:00 heroku[run.3244]: Awaiting client
2015-06-01T10:03:32.600901+00:00 heroku[run.3244]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2015-06-01T10:03:38.258094+00:00 heroku[run.3244]: State changed from up to complete
2015-06-01T10:03:38.244833+00:00 heroku[run.3244]: Process exited with status 0
2015-06-01T10:03:32.823266+00:00 heroku[run.3244]: State changed from starting to up
2015-06-01T10:04:29.843040+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=young-refuge-9638.herokuapp.com request_id=578796a0-31a8-4790-9239-748c80ed2d22 fwd="49.197.32.79" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-06-01T10:04:30.665001+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=young-refuge-9638.herokuapp.com request_id=5d1ac2bf-c518-4602-a000-3ef0832ca46b fwd="49.197.32.79" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-06-01T10:04:40.782417+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-06-01T10:04:45.059651+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 4406 -e production`
2015-06-01T10:04:47.102588+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: bin/rails: No such file or directory
2015-06-01T10:04:48.126555+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2015-06-01T10:04:48.144047+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-06-01T10:05:23.648652+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by ryan@ryandrake.com
2015-06-01T10:05:28.628805+00:00 heroku[run.7471]: Awaiting client
2015-06-01T10:05:28.669860+00:00 heroku[run.7471]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2015-06-01T10:05:28.983454+00:00 heroku[run.7471]: State changed from starting to up
2015-06-01T10:05:35.429377+00:00 heroku[run.7471]: State changed from up to complete
2015-06-01T10:05:35.419008+00:00 heroku[run.7471]: Process exited with status 0
2015-06-01T10:20:05.868334+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by ryan@ryandrake.com
2015-06-01T10:20:10.445560+00:00 heroku[run.8146]: Awaiting client
2015-06-01T10:20:10.488241+00:00 heroku[run.8146]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2015-06-01T10:20:10.799424+00:00 heroku[run.8146]: State changed from starting to up
2015-06-01T10:20:17.437232+00:00 heroku[run.8146]: Process exited with status 0
2015-06-01T10:20:17.454791+00:00 heroku[run.8146]: State changed from up to complete
2015-06-01T10:21:57.009973+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=young-refuge-9638.herokuapp.com request_id=aabc7f00-2e00-491f-86d8-2eecc1f08beb fwd="49.197.32.79" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-06-01T10:21:58.012951+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=young-refuge-9638.herokuapp.com request_id=bdbf4755-cd80-45be-a44f-72cbd85406cd fwd="49.197.32.79" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-06-01T10:21:58.314822+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=young-refuge-9638.herokuapp.com request_id=efd2ee8e-6981-4fa6-adfa-590d2e50d83f fwd="49.197.32.79" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

It's running fine in development. What have I missed?

Comment: `bundler: command not found: thin`, is thin in your Gemfile?

Comment: Thin is in my gemfile under development. Why would that be causing the issue?

Comment: Remove all the mentions of the gems that are repeated twice  , also move the gem thin out of development and re-push the Gemfile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run this on your local as you are missing a bin folder and commit on heroku.

```
rake rails:update:bin
```

Reference: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails4

Comment: Adnan, YOU SAVED ME SO MUCH TIME! Thank you. Wow, seriously been searching for this answer for the last two hours.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add the bin directory to your repo according to a similar question: ["bin/rails: No such file or directory" w/ Ruby 2 & Rails 4 on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17583439/bin-rails-no-such-file-or-directory-w-ruby-2-rails-4-on-heroku)

From their answer:

1. Remove bin from ~/.gitignore
2. Run `rake rails:update:bin`
3. Run `bundle install`
4. Commit your changes with git add . and `git commit -m "Add bin back"`. You   should see that the bin has now been created or added if it was missing previously.
5. Push your changes to Heroku with `git push heroku master`

Comment: I did initially follow your steps but removing bin from ~/.gitignore didn't immediately add back in the bin. So i've edited your answer as a result to include Adnan's solution as well.